# Does hitting metals magnetize them?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was on my workshop lab today and had to [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filing_%28metalworking%29) (rub on metal surface with rough surface to smooth-en it) an iron bar. It made iron dust fall of the surface. To mark some points on the bar I then had to hammer a pointed another Iron bar over the former. What I noticed is that the iron dust that had previously fallen off were clinging on the top circumference of the pointed bar.

I have two probable explanations for this

1. The iron dust being small acted as magnets as there are fewer magnetic domains and they essentially align on single direction so that the dust were attracted.
2. Hitting the top of bar somehow could have magnetized the bar so that the dust were attracted

Am I correct with one or both of these explanations?

Answer (score 5):

The impact of the hammer with the iron nail causes the magnetic domains within the nail to break loose from their current orientation. The Earth's magnetic field will then reposition the domains into a new orientation parallel with the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: If you have a magnet to begin with, hitting it with a hammer can demagnetize it.

Comment: @Luftwaffe I doubt that the magnetic field of the earth would be enough to create the effect described in the OP.

Comment: @gonenc, irrespective of Your doubts, smaller ships (esp. mine sweepers) were rotated 180 ° north-south on the wharfs at around half of the work.

Answer (score 1):

Luftwaffe is probably right, but also possibly the filings or the bar were already very slightly magnetized.  In that case the hammer impact on the table shakes the filings around, removing the friction that keeps them from moving toward the iron bar.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the doubters that posted above. I just performed an experiment with my daughter, where we struck a sewing needle with a hammer and then suspended the needle in water. It indeed was imbued with magnetism and pointed north. We performed the experiment before stricking the needle and it drifted aimlessly.